# Round 3 Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I know this has been answered in previous threads, but after following all the solutions i have been unable to solve this issue.

So I am using spring & thymeleaf on top of hibernate with a mySQL database.
Im trying to register a userlogin object to the database by means of a simple form, but the system crashes immediately upon running and keeps showing the error:

Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Note* I am able to add a club object to the database by using the same implementation so I reckon maybe it's to do with the extra variables associated with the userlogin object?

First post so please go easy!

Here is my controller code (second two methods are the userlogin related ones):

```
package com.FYP.Club.controller;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
  @Autowired
    UserLoginRepository userRepository;

  @Autowired
        ClubRepository clubRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/registerclub", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Club club) {
        return "clubindex";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/club", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addNewPost(@Valid Club club, Model model) {
        clubRepository.save(club);
        model.addAttribute("clubName", club.getClubName());
        return "clubresult";
    }


@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(UserLogin user) {
    return "index";

}


@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNewPost(@Valid UserLogin user, Model model) {
    user.setUserStatus(true);
    model.addAttribute("email", user.getEmail());
    return "result";
  }

}
```

Here is the index.html page which has the user form:

```
<h3>Register</h3>

<form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>First name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone:</td>
            <td><input type="number" th:field="*{phone}" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>

            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{email}" /></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>

            <td>Address:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{address}" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{password}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>UserType:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{userType}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>

</td>
```

Here is the userlogin model:

```
@Entity
public class UserLogin {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Long phone;
private String email;
private String address;
private String password;
private Boolean userStatus;
private String userType;


public UserLogin()
{

}

public UserLogin(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, Long phone,
        String email, String address, String password, Boolean userStatus,
        String userType) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
    this.address = address;
    this.password = password;
    this.userStatus = userStatus;
    this.userType = userType;
}

public String getUserType() {
    return userType;
}

public void setUserType(String userType) {
    this.userType = userType;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Long getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(Long phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Boolean getUserStatus() {
    return userStatus;
}

public void setUserStatus(Boolean userStatus) {
    this.userStatus = userStatus;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the UserLogin object before use it, as below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new UserLogin()); //add model to view


    return "index";

}
```

and if you are using the @Valid Annotation you need capture the errors in a BindingResult variable, something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNewPost(@Valid UserLogin user, Model model,
                         BindingResult errors) {

    user.setUserStatus(true);
    model.addAttribute("email", user.getEmail());
    return "result";
  }
```

Comment: Jorge L. Morla Thank you for your help! That solved the error